# How to include layer symbology in ArcGIS Online popup

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade, arcgis-online-webmap

Is it possible to include a layer's symbology within the popup in ArcGIS Online? Below is an example of 2 different types of symbology that I'm using in my ArcGIS Online map. The fork/spoon icon represents food pantry locations and the brown house icon represents affordable housing.

[image: maps with two types of symbology]

Here's an example of how I'd like my popup to look.  I want to replace the icon (pointed in red) with the actual icon from my map.

[image: example of house icon wanted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can access the symbology used in a layer from the pop-up or using Arcade. What you can do is place an image into it and that has a URL. You could explore the idea of uploading the image separately to AGOL then for each row in your feature layer have a URL path to the image? Explore the help file on Configuring pop-ups.

Comment: Thanks so much Hornbydd, that was a great suggestion and it worked out great.